# Jquery - conditional contain of the closest elem

Tags: jquery, if-statement, contains, closest

I am trying to refresh a page when I click on the "delete elem", only if the closest "product title" contains a specific text. The jquery  code below does not work..
If you have any idea, thank you.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $(".delete-item").on( "click", function( reloadEvent ) {
    if( $( reloadEvent.target ).closest(".Product-details").find(".Product-title:contains('XYZ')").lenght)  
      {location.reload.bind(location);}
    else {}
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Product-details">
  <div class="Product-header">
    <span class="Product-title">Product title A</span>
  <div/>
  <div class="Product-footer">
    <div class="delete-action">
      <a href="#" class="delete-item">DELETE</a>`
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Product-details">
  <div class="Product-header">
    <span class="Product-title">Product title B</span>
  <div/>
  <div class="Product-footer">
    <div class="delete-action">
      <a href="#" class="delete-item">DELETE</a>`
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think because of spelling mistake of  "length" it is not working,please at first make it correct

Comment: Yes my bad, + I changed the refresh function into : {location.reload();}  and it works perfectly, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll write that:

```
  $(".delete-item").on( "click", function(  ) {
    if( $( this ).closest(".Product-details").find(".Product-title:contains('XYZ')").length)  
      {location.reload.bind(location);}
    else {}
   })
```

Comment: It works well, I just changed the refresh function into { location.reload();}, thank you :)

Comment: glad to help you, dont forget to validate and upvote the answer to close the question